# How to convert a RectangleF to PointF[] for drawing?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing, drawing2d

I'm not sure if the question is too trivial but, I need to use the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yaya8aaw.aspx) overload of the method `Graphics.DrawImage`:

```
public void DrawImage(
    Image image,
    PointF[] destPoints,
    RectangleF srcRect,
    GraphicsUnit srcUnit,
    ImageAttributes imageAttr
)
```

I have a `RectangleF` as destination rectangle, so I need to convert the `RectangleF` to `PointF[]` but the [example in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yaya8aaw.aspx#Y1100) confused me a little bit because it only uses three points to define a parallelogram.

How could I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason they use three points is the `DrawImage` method calculates the fourth point based on the other three points to ensure a valid paralellagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yaya8aaw.aspx#Y1100):

> The destPoints parameter specifies three points of a parallelogram. The three PointF structures represent the **upper-left**, **upper-right**, and **lower-left** corners of the parallelogram. The fourth point is extrapolated from the first three to form a parallelogram.

So you can construct your point array in the following way:

```
    private PointF[] GetPoints(RectangleF rectangle)
    {
        return new PointF[3]
        { 
            new PointF(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top),
            new PointF(rectangle.Right, rectangle.Top),
            new PointF(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom)
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you create it by just constructing the array?

(From memory) Where d is the destination RectangleF:

```
destPoints[] = new PointF[4] { new PointF(d.Left, d.Top), new PointF(d.Right, d.Top), new PointF(d.Right, d.Bottom), new PointF(d.Left, d.Bottom) };
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even notice the Top, Bottom, Left, Right properties.  That should do the trick.

Comment: If you need to do it often, I'd write a `ToPoints` extension method for RectangleF to easily reuse it.